# Problema com função para popular cidades de acordo com estado escolhido, função change()

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
$(function(){
    $("#estadoPaciente").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../controller/ajax.selectCidades.php?id="+id,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(res) {
                $("#cidadePaciente").append(res);
                $("#cidadePaciente").selectpicker('refresh');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

No PHP:

```
<?php
include_once 'controller.seguranca.php';
include_once 'controller.cidade.php';

$id_estado = $_GET['id'];

$cidade = new CidadeController();
$retornoCidade = $cidade->selectCidadePorEstado($id_estado);
if(count($retornoCidade) > 0)
{
    foreach ($retornoCidade as $dados => $value) 
    {       
        echo '<option value='.$retornoCidade[$dados]->id_GRcidade.'>'.utf8_encode($retornoCidade[$dados]->nome_GRcidade).'</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Está funcionando esse código, o problema é o seguinte:

Se o usuario escolher, por exemplo, o estado da Bahia, vai aparecer as cidades do estado da Bahia no `<select id="cidadePaciente>`, porém se ele mudar pro estado de São Paulo, o `<select id="cidadePaciente>` continua mostrando as cidades do estado da Bahia, mesmo o usuario mudando o `<select id="estadoPaciente>` para estado de São Paulo. (Os estados escolhidos são apenas exemplos, o problema acontece pra qualquer estado escolhido).

Comment: Mude `$("#cidadePaciente").append(res);` para `$("#cidadePaciente").html(res);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve mudar a linha do seu javascript:

```
$("#cidadePaciente").append(res);
```

Para:

```
$("#cidadePaciente").html(res);
```

Também deve fazer a seguinte alteração em seu `PHP`, crie uma variável ex: `$html = ""` abaixo da variável `$id_estado`, depois altere a linha:

```
echo '<option value='.$retornoCidade[$dados]->id_GRcidade.'>'.utf8_encode($retornoCidade[$dados]->nome_GRcidade).'</option>';
```

Para:

```
$html .= '<option value='.$retornoCidade[$dados]->id_GRcidade.'>'.utf8_encode($retornoCidade[$dados]->nome_GRcidade).'</option>';
```

E fora do `foreach` e ainda dentro do `if` adicione:

```
echo $html;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!